# How return for other functions the ID?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-picker

How return for other functions the ID?

```
function pickerCallback(data) {
  var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];

  if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
    **var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];**
    var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
    var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
      google.script.run.doSomething(id);

    alert(id);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
      '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a><br>ID: ' + id;
    } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
   }   }
```

Comment: Is it not working? could you explain more your issue?

Comment: Is this what you are using?  [Google Documentation - Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/index)

Comment: I'm assuming that the line you have outlined in double asterisks is the line that you are having trouble with?  `**var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];**`